# Named capture in PHP using regex

Tags: php, regex

How can I use named capture with regex in PHP? Can anyone give me a working example?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: Here is another reference: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html. I find this entire regex dedicated site to be an *excellent* resource. Especially this page: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html, and this advanced technique page (skip to the end for the true shortcut trick) https://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html.

Comment: @SherylHohman linked reference CSS is messed up

Answer (score 57):

Doesn't work with replace , only useful for match in php

```
$test="yet another test";

preg_match('/(?P<word>t[^s]+)/',$test,$matches);

var_dump($matches['word']);
```

Comment: thanks. but what is t[^s]+ ??
consider i wanna find any thing between <tag> and </tag> into matches['word']. what i should do ?

Comment: [^s] =anything except letter s,  I actually meant to write slash + s for space, but mistyped it but not important part.  you could ask your other question in new one, maybe somebody will help you before me with that.

Comment: @sataho You can match anything between the tag using something like `/<tag>(?P<word>.*?)<\/tag>/`.

Comment: now if i want to do it with 2 tags using 1 regular exp . can I use it ?
/<tag1>(?P<word>.*?)<\/tag1> <tag2>(?P<word>.*?)<\/tag2>/

Comment: no you can't do it like that.  you need to read more about regular expression format: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/you-dont-know-anything-about-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 49):

According [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php)

> PHP 5.2.2 introduced two alternative syntaxes `(?<name>pattern)` and `(?'name'pattern)`

So you'll get same result using:

```
<?php
preg_match('/(?P<test>.+)/', $string, $matches);  // basic syntax
preg_match('/(?<test>.+)/', $string, $matches);   // alternative
preg_match("/(?'test'.+)/", $string, $matches);   // alternative
```

[Check result on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/84q9T)