# How to detect a string with specific pattern from a larger string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a long string from which I want to detect and replace with some other text. Suppose my text is `'my first name is @[[Rameez]] and second name is @[[Rami]]'`. I want to detect @[[Rameez]] and replace with Rameez dynamically to all likewise strings.

Comment: What's the problem in detecting `@[[Rameez]]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Specific version

```
// Find Rameez specifically
$re = '/@\[\[(?<name>Rameez)\]\]/i'; // Use i flag if you to want a case insensitive search
$str = 'my first name is @[[Rameez]] and second name is @[[Rami]].\nDid I forget to mention that my name is @[[rameez]]?'; 

echo preg_replace($re, '$1', '**RAMEEZ** (specific)<br/>' . PHP_EOL);
```

### Generic version

#### Regex

```
@\[\[(?<name>.+?)\]\]
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

`(?<name> .. )` represents here a named capturing group. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6971356/363573) for details.

#### Sample code

```
// Find any name enclosed by @[[ and ]].
$re = '/@\[\[(?<name>Rameez)\]\]/i'; // Use i flag if you to want a case insensitive search
$str = 'my first name is @[[Rameez]] and second name is @[[Rami]].\nDid I forget to mention that my name is @[[rameez]]?'; 

echo preg_replace($re, '$1', '**RAMEEZ** (generic)<br/>' . PHP_EOL);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vS2mD4/1)

Comment: Thanks Stephen..... Awesome answer with full explanation and  special thanks for letting know about the reg-ex tester demo site.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
preg_replace('/@\[\[(\w+)\]\]/', "$1", $string);
```

`[` and `]` need to be escaped because they have special meaning in a regex.
This will replace any string `@[[whatever]]` by `whatever`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regex pattern then user it to match, find and replace a given string. Here's example:

```
string input = "This is   text with   far  too   much   " + 
                     "whitespace.";
      string pattern = "\\s+";
      string replacement = " ";
      Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
      string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

It's C# code but you can apply it to any language really. In your case you can substitute the pattern with something like `string pattern = "@[[Rameez]]";` and then use different replacement: `string replacement = "Rameez";`
I hope that makes sense.